# Why would reading a certifcate in a server.js started by a process cause the process to terminate?

Tags: c#, node.js, ssl, service, process

I have a process which, on start, runs a node.js server. Trying to add HTTPS to the server results in the process which the server is attached to terminating. What could be causing this?

The process is started by a service written in C#. The process is then attached onto by the server.js. I've tried debugging the service to see which path of execution leads to the process being terminated by I couldn't track it down. Removing the lines form server.js that read the certificates results in the process not being terminated. However, I can't work out why that would be the case.

To read the certificates:

```
var privatekey = fs.readFileSync("xxx.pem", "utf8");
var certificate = fs.readFileSync("xxx.cert", "utf8");
var credentials = { key: privatekey, cert: certificate };
```

The setup of the Process:

```cs
            var nodePath = GetNodePath();

            // Get the path to the web files
            var serverPath = ".\\server\\server.js";

            // Create the process arguments
            ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
            info.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName( Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location );
            info.CreateNoWindow = true;
            info.UseShellExecute = false;
            info.FileName = nodePath;


            info.EnvironmentVariables.Add( "NODE_ENV", "production" );
            info.Arguments = $"{serverPath} --max-old-space=200";
```

I have an event handler for the exit of the process which is mostly below:

```cs
private static void webProcess_Exited( object sender, EventArgs e )
        {

            // Make sure we haven't restarted more than 10 times
            if ( restartCount > 5 )
            {
                var message = "The xxx web service is being shut down due to the nodejs process expectantly terminating too many times.";

                // Log to the event log
                ShutdownService();
            }
            else
            {
                var message = "The nodejs process was expectantly terminated, restarting the process in 5 seconds.";

                // Log to the event log
                Thread.Sleep( 5000 );
                //Starts the process/node.js server again
                Start();
            }
        }
```

Starting server.js reading the certificates works fine. Removing the lines reading the certificate and running the service also works fine. But, for some reason, when reading the certificates and starting the node.js server through the service, it terminates/starts before terminating for good, as above.

Would anyone what could be causing this? Or suggest ways to troubleshoot this further?

Comment: What's your working directory when launching from the service? Is it trying to load them from the correct path?

Comment: @FrankerZ  the assembly is in the same folder as the server folder. The server folder houses the server.js and the pem/cert files

In my question I had the below to set the working directory:
```c#
info.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName( Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location );
```
I assume this would mean the working directory is actually one level above the server.js

Comment: Please don't edit your question to include the answer. Instead: Add an answer down below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Investigating the comment by @FrankerZ , I found that moving the certificate file from the directory the server.js is held to where the process assembly is fixed my issue. The reason the process terminated is, I assume, the working directory was set in the c# service to be where the assembly is (one level above the server.js). However, the certificate files were stored in the level below (alongside server.js). Thus, when I read the certificates, it is attempting to read them from the directory above where they actually are, resulting in the process terminating.